# c# optional parameters in constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, optional-parameters

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program a = new Program();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public Program()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("constructor without parameters");
        }

        public Program(int a = 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("optional parameters constructor");
        }
    }
```

Why is the second constructor used and why is it not forbidden (same signature)?

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]. This program does _not_ call the parameterized constructor, and the signatures are not the same anyway.

Comment: thanks i did search, but did not find the related answers

Comment: The second should only be called if you actually pass an `int`, thus making the optional parameter useless.

Comment: @Fabian -- I always wonder about a response like yours: "I did search but didn't find anything."  This is 2017; search engines have been around since I believe 1996, 21 years.  I plugged in a very simple search phrase in google and came up with the duplicate answer within the first 2 or 3 results.  So I'm not buying that you did a search.

Comment: i found answers on what constructor is choosen, but i didn't find any with a reason.

Comment: @Fabian -- Maybe if you took a step back and realized this behavior is not just limited to constructors, but rather applies to all methods.